# python set intersection with object sets

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, set, intersection, boto

I am working with amazon boto and I have 2 lists. List 1 contains Instance objects. List 2 contains InstanceInfo objects. Both objects have a attribute called id. I need to get a list of Instance objects which id exists in the InstanceInfo list.

```
l1 = [Instance:i-04072534, Instance:i-06072536, Instance:i-08072538, Instance:i-0a07253a, Instance:i-e68fa1d6, Instance:i-e88fa1d8, Instance:i-ea8fa1da, Instance:i-ec8fa1dc]

l2 = [InstanceInfo:i-ec8fa1dc, InstanceInfo:i-ea8fa1da, InstanceInfo:i-e88fa1d8, InstanceInfo:i-e68fa1d6]
```

Wanted result:

```
l3 = [Instance:i-ec8fa1dc, Instance:i-ea8fa1da, Instance:i-e88fa1d8, Instance:i-e68fa1d6]
```

Right now I have it working through:

```
l3= []
for a in l1  
    for b in l2:
        if a.id == b.id:
            l3.append(a)
```

However, I have been told that I should replace this using set intersection. I have been looking at examples and it looks very straightforward. Yet I don't see any examples working with objects.

I've been playing around for a bit and theoretically I can see it work, yet there might be some 'advanced' syntax that I may not know off. I am still learning python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is something faster than Marcin's answer (while being similar):

```
ids_l1 = set(x.id for x in l1)  # All ids in list 1
intersection = [item for item in l2 if item.id in ids_l1]  # Only those elements of l2 with an id in l1
```

It is important to pre-calculate `ids_l1` and to not write `if item.id in set(…)`, as the set would be reconstructed each time (as the full test expression is re-evaluated for each element `item`).

Python sets give you fast element membership tests (`in`). Such tests are much faster with sets than with lists (as the elements of a list must be read one by one, whereas the elements of a set are "hashed").

Comment: And here you are right, because intersecting is out of list creation. But Marcin's solution is slowest.

Comment: @MateuszWoźniak I have no doubt your solution would be slowest;your ideone simply says "result: not running", which is perhaps best, given that you don't even use the usual `timeit` library, but rather a solution based on system time.

Comment: This works, but what is the difference between this code and Mateusz' code? except that this one uses set() and appearantly is faster?

Comment: @Marcin go create better test and paste link to it :)

Comment: @MateuszWoźniak: I see what you mean: the calculation of the intersection, in Marcin's answer, is redone for each element in `l2`, which slows things down.

Comment: @KevindeBoer: The difference is that testing membership with `element in my_set` is *much* faster than doing `element in my_list`.  The reason is that lists are not optimized for membership tests, while sets are. Lists are good for other purposes (like appending elements).

Comment: @MateuszWoźniak No, why don't you create an appropriate test.

Comment: @EOL exactly - classic mistake with comprehension lists. And I know that sets are faster, but I wrote quick and dirty solution for lists from question.

Comment: @Marcin - I've made one already, and it shows that my method is faster so you can prove that I'm wrong by creating your one. btw your method gives correct result, so you don't have -1 from me :)

Comment: @MateuszWoźniak: we pointed out to Marcin that he should calculate the intersection out of his loop, and his edited answer now shows a much faster implementation than his original one. I indeed don't think that there is any need for any additional speed tests. :)

Comment: @MateuszWoźniak Actually, your test shows nothing whatsoever. It has no output, and does not use a valid method for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Your method may be relatively efficient for smallish lists.

With sets, you would have to extract the ids, calculate the intersection of ids, and then collect the items into your new list. Something like:

```
set1 = set(x.id for x in l1)
set2 = set(x.id for x in l2)
intersection_ids = set1 & set2
intersection_list = [item for item in l2 if item.id in intersection_ids]
```

You can make this a little more efficient by scanning over the shorter list, or by storing your objects in a dict.

Comment: No down vote, because sets *are* fast for element lookup. However, there is really no need to go through list `l2` twice (both in `set(…)` and in `for item in l2`), as shown in my answer.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
# get ids of elements in second list
l2_ids = [x.id for x in l2]
# get elements from first list that have ids in second
l3 = [x for x in l1 if x.id in l2_ids]
```

Comment: -1 Why would you test for membership in a list unless the list is guaranteed to be very, very small?

Comment: This is a quick way to get intersect of lists that Kevin post in his question. It works, so I don't know why you pushed -1. But ok, it's you opinion.

Comment: The `in` test is slow: this algorithm is in O(n_l1 * n_l2). I would not recommend using a slow algorithm when Python offers some fast and simple solutions (like Marcin's).

Comment: so try this in your console: http://ideone.com/o8Xa1  Intersecting sets is more expensive

Comment: @MateuszWoźniak Note that this is an effect of the lists being small, which is why I said so in my comment.

Comment: 10000 elements is small list? In your code you are creating union of two sets in every step of comprehension list, so this always will be slower than simple `in` which of course is also slower than creating set outside (as EOL wrote).

Comment: @MateuszWoźniak I'm not talking about your ideone, which has no output, and uses a ridiculous method to time the efficiency of each approach.